# How to fix Warning: map service token not specified

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, maps, bing-maps

I'm working on an app in Xamarin that uses a map.
The map seems to work fine because it does show my location, but it keeps showing me "warning map service token not specified" underneath the map.

The Api key type is basic/UWP and it's enabled.
I put the Api key in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init("myApiKey");
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LoadApplication(new BarApp.App());
    }
```

And I also checked "Location" in Package.appxmanifest

I get no other errors, and everything else seems to work fine, so i'm really confused what the problem could be :/

Thanks in advance! (:

-Jeroen

Explanation I used: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Comment: not sure how the .Init() parses "myApiKey", but are you sure that he isn't using `"myApiKey"` has your key?

Comment: There is plenty of info if you search the internet.  Here is one solution : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/acf5d351-4220-4ce4-b33f-d58f263050ec/uwpwarning-map-service-token-not-specified?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: @diomonogatari I used the tutorial provided bij Xamarin (will add the link in the post). The "myApiKey" is a placeholder, I do use an actual api key.

Comment: @jdweng I've searched, and i''e already seen that exact page. Many answers focus on either ceating a new key because the other one might be old (mine is newly created) or that the type is wrong (had wrong type at first, but not anymore)

Comment: You may want to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help located issue.  You may not be putting the token in the request properly and the sniffer will show you the error.  You just need to filter on the HTTP messages.  You should see the error coming from the server and then verify the previous message you sent to the server.

Comment: @jdweng Alright, thanks, I will give it a try (:

Comment: @jdweng no luck :c Didn't find anything, might be encrypted I guess

Comment: Error messages are not encrypted.  Did you see any http packets in sniffer?  If you are not seeing any http packets then the API is not sending any packets.  So that would mean the API is missing setup info, or the API is using TCP and not http.

Comment: @jdweng No http packets, but I did indeed get a lot of TCP packets. Will check all of them first thing tomorrow, because I have to go real soon.

Comment: Just check the ones with the right source and destination IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The map seems to work fine because it does show my location, but it keeps showing me "warning map service token not specified"

The native [`MapControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn637004) is `BingMap` in UWP platform. According to [Request a maps authentication key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key), Your Universal Windows app must be authenticated before it can use the `MapControl` and map services in the `Windows.Services.Maps namespace`. The authentication key in Xamarin official  code sample was expired. You could request a new maps authentication key from the [**Bing Maps Developer Center**](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/) and add it to your app.